# SQL Update column with subquery giving duplicate results

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to this forum and to the SQL Language. I have ran into a problem when trying to update a column from one table with some results using 2 tables:

I have the Table Orders, as it follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders]
 (
[IdOrder] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
[IdLine] INT NOT NULL,
[OrderNo] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
[Description] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
[StartDate] DATETIME NULL, 
[EndDate] DATETIME NULL,
[Setpoint] INT NULL,
[Score] FLOAT NULL, 
[Status] NCHAR(10) NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Line_IdArea] FOREIGN KEY ([IdLine]) REFERENCES [Line]  ([IdLine]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Then I have this other table. This 2 are in a one to many relationship

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Productivity]
(
[IdProductivity] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
[IdOrder] INT NULL,
[Cont] INT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Product_Order_IdOrder] FOREIGN KEY ([IdOrder]) REFERENCES      [Orders]([IdOrder]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

I have som data on this tables and when i execute this query the results are just fine:

Query:

```
SELECT (CAST(Cont AS FLOAT) / CAST(Setpoint AS FLOAT)*100 ) AS col from Productivity LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders ON Productivity.IdOrder = Orders.IdOrder
```

Result:
[Query returning 4 rows with correct results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsMo7.png)

Then when I apply a subquery to Update the Order table, in the Score column with the following query:

```
UPDATE Orders
SET Score = col 
FROM (SELECT (CAST(Cont AS FLOAT) / CAST(Setpoint AS FLOAT)*100 ) AS col from Productivity LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders ON Productivity.IdOrder = Orders.IdOrder) 
AS query
```

I get this Result:[Query inserting only first and last result and duplicating them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFQj8.png)

Please let me know if I need to provide more information about this and thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do this as a sub query just a normal update

```
UPDATE Orders
SET Score = (CAST(Cont AS FLOAT) / CAST(Setpoint AS FLOAT)*100 ) 
FROM Productivity LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders 
ON Productivity.IdOrder = Orders.IdOrder
```